# Nexus 4 and Android 5

Tags: updates, nexus-4, factory-reset, stock-android, 5.0-lollipop

I had my nexus 4 rooted , i have heard that rooted phone would not get updated over WIFI
so i Factory Reset my phone , will it now get the update or not?
no signe of update notification yet

Comment: A factory-reset does not unroot your device.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a rooted device, you most likely will not be able to install OTA updates (over the air). Factory resetting the device will not un-root the device so the best way of updating it is to do the following:

Get the factory image you wish to install (in your case, lollipop) from the Google developers [website](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images)

Flash that image by following [this tutorial](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-update-nexus-4-android-5-0-lollipop-lrx21t-via-official-factory-image-1474933) or similar ones on the web.

Comment: AFAIK, rooting itself doesn't prevent OTA, at least that's what I experienced when updating from JB to KitKat.

Comment: Hmm, that's different to what I found.  The phone would say an update was available and I could download it and try to install it.  The installation would fail and it would boot up to the version it had before with no changes.

Comment: I could be wrong though. I flashed Lollipop since I didn't want to wait for OTA. Turned out I did what I should do without knowing it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Having read up on it I think it can vary with phone model.  The Nexus range certainly will not accept OTA updated if they are rooted.

Comment: Pre Android 5.0, I don't think being rooted will prevent the OTA installing by itself. The OTA will verify that the files in the /system partition is the same as it expects, so any modifications may cause the update to fail. I have applied updates prior to Android 5.0 on a rooted device and they have worked fine. As of Android 5.0 this seems to have changed as it appears to verify the whole partition rather than the files it's patching. I'm not sure if this applies to the update to 5.0 or just updates once on 5.0.